# How can I check if Warren Buffett or Berkshire Hathaway is parking cash more than usual?

Tags: online-data-source, research

Purportedly, [the world’s wealthiest investors are waiting for stocks to drop further before buying again](https://www.reddit.com/r/investing/comments/gadlsq/worlds_richest_are_waiting_for_new_dip_in_stocks/). How can I verify this online for Warren Buffett and his Berkshire Hathaway? Any IRS documents? I want to know if he parked more cash than usual.

Comment: Annual reports from Berkshire Hathaway ??

Answer (score 2):

As @DumbCoder coder suggested, filed annual reports is the only real public information you have, but this is at a point in time, and may be arbitrarily abnormal; for tax reasons.

You also have public statements, like the one you saw. These are again at a point in time, and there may be ulterior motives for these — both from Warren Buffett and the news reporter. So biases will exist.

The information you are wanting is probably needed on a daily or weekly basis, since you want to engage with the market as quickly as Berkshire Hathaway do.

This just isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

> according to a poll by UBS Global Wealth Management.

Hello, I'm Warren Buffett and some UBS GWM asked ME, in poll, if I think that it's good time to invest or to wait. Because I want to make money I will say to them that I'll wait while I invest so whoever listens to them will buy from me.

And any other combination of possible answers.

And obligatory Dilbert comic :

[image: 1995 comic]

Updated version for 2013:

[image: 2013 comic]